# How to set path cooke for Plug.Session in phoenix app?

Tags: session, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this configuration in my `config.exs`

```
      plug_session: [
        store: :cookie,
        key: "foo_key",
        signing_salt: "XXX"
      ]
```

and the cookie created is for the whole domain whose PATH is `/`.

How can I set a specific PATH for the cookie session?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the path using `path: "/some/path"` as mentioned in [the docs for Plug.Session](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Session.html#module-options):

```
plug_session: [
  store: :cookie,
  key: "foo_key",
  signing_salt: "XXX",
  path: "/some/path"
]
```